# Changing font sizes using a @mediaquery

Tags: html, css, fonts, media-queries

In a website I'm making, I'm wanting to change the font sizes so when the screen gets smaller the font size will fit the screen. Trying to use a @media query so the fonts change size but it doesn't seem to be working. This is the code for the site;

```
 <div class="row members Rou" style="background-color:#000000">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> Rou Reynolds </h2>
        <img src="Rou.png" class="image-full-width band ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p class="paragraph-push-down"> 
                 blah blah blah
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is what I've tried to place in the style sheet, This is how I want it to look when the screen is smaller;

```
.paragraph-push-down {
margin-top: 80px;
text-align: left;
font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

And this for when the screen is full sized;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 430px) {
.paragraph-push-down {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: century gothic;
        font-size: 20em;
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Sorry if I've explained this badly, Only a first year uni student and don't quite know what I'm doing and not that great at this sort of stuff.

Comment: Set a viewport like this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: + Just and FYI you can shorten your media query to just `@media (max-width: 430px) {  }`

Comment: @Aaron maybe he has diffrent media queries for screen and print ;p

Comment: `max-width: 430px` means screen sizes 430 px and *smaller*. Did you mean `min-width: 430px` (based on the "this is for when the screen is full sized" comment)?

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/47u6gn22/. What is your base font size?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `rem` units to scale your font in this case, and a mobile-first approach. Here's the basic idea.

1. Define a base font size for your body element.
2. Define the font size for your element using `rem` units. For example `1rem` will cause the font to be `16px`.
3. Define the font size for your element at larger viewport sizes in the `media` query using `rem` units.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1rem; // 16px
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 430px) {
  p {
    font-size: 2rem; // 16 * 2 = 32px
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Here's some text.</p>
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qvbktw2q/).